# Do any judicial bodies in England have inquisitorial powers?

Tags: england-and-wales, court, tribunal

England mostly follows common law, an adversarial system which is the opposite of the inquisitorial judicial system.

That said, are there deviations and variations from this in any of its judicial bodies, including courts, and tribunals, and any others?

Comment: Related question: [Do tribunals have inquisitorial powers?](https://law.stackexchange.com/a/90560/35069)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Judicial bodies are typically not inquisitorial

That said, under the doctrine of Parliamentary Sovereignty in the UK, they can make special purpose courts that are inquisitorial - the Coroner’s Court being an example.

Tribunals can be because they are administrative decision makers, not judicial decision makers. The statute that creates them will tell them how to operate. The granddaddy of all tribunals, the [Royal Commission](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Royal_commission), is explicitly inquisitorial.